# How to handle sorting "strings"?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sorting

Say that I got a orderedlist with items, each item can be sorted up and down in this list. The first thought would be to have a SortOrder of int(ex 1-10). The problem with this is that I always have to update at least 2 items when sorting (item 3 takes the place of item 4 and thereby switches sort value). If I place a new item at position 3 all items > 3 would have to change there sortOrder.

So to avoid this I could use larger intervalls for example :

```
N1 : 10 000
N2 : 20 000
N3 : 30 000
N4 : 40 000
N5 : 50 000
```

If N4 would be sorted up one level it would look like this :

```
N1 : 10 000
N2 : 20 000
N4 : 25 000
N3 : 30 000
N5 : 50 000
```

My question is how to handle this the best way in C#? What datatype should I use? How do I avoid to regenerate the entire list(when no sorting can be done anymore) as often?

My own thought are to store it as a Decimal in both code and database.

Comment: This looks like a proposed solution rather than a problem. Could you explain the problem you're trying to solve? I don't think using an int or decimal or whatever to sort is a bad thing; it's just that the question doesn't explain *why* you'd insert a new item or change the sort order of an existing item. If you explain that I think you'll have a better chance of a good answer.

Comment: What's the issue with updating/swapping both numbers?

Comment: I try to make as little updates as possible and this includes roundtrips to the databas and also GUI updates.

Comment: And there is one more thing, there will be alot of users sorting at the same time and I want to avoid locking everything.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use is to have a dedicated DisplayOrder column with int datatype; I do (usually) index the column but not with a unique index. That way it's not too painful to swap two items by updating the value. Often (and by default) I don't need to make the value visible through the UI so the actual values never really matter. If it's important to have unique values then that can work too - I have a proc that I run to 're-base' the order values from 1 when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a "sort order" field in code?

If you have the items in memory in a list or some other container, then the order of the items is the sorted order.

You only need to assign a numeric value when you're persisting the data - to a database or otherwise. Then, when you retrieve the items to repopulate the in-memory data, fetch them and add to the list in the sorted order.

This methodology allows for any re-ordering of the items, and also deletion of items, without having to maintain the sort order values until the point where you come to save the data.

Comment: The problem is that any sororder changes that are made will have to be saved to databse. So Im trying to do as little updates as possible.